# How do i show the content through ajax in a popup

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress

I want to show a popup in which content comes from the other file.
Right now i am using this code to show a popup when the content for the popup is present on the same page.

```
 jQuery(".item").click(function(e) {
    var currentID = jQuery(this).attr("id");

    jQuery.ajax({
        method: "POST",
        url: "some.php",
        data: {
            name: "John",
            location: "Boston"
        }
    })


    .done(function(msg) {
        jQuery(".popup-overlay").html(msg);
        jQuery("." + currentID).fadeIn(300, function() {
            jQuery(this).focus();
        });
            jQuery(".popup-overlay").show();
        });
  });
```

Can i some how put the content to be shown in popup in other file and then pass the path of the file some how in above code

this will the code in ajax.php

```
<?php include("wp-load.php"); ?> 

  <div class="popup-overlay">
  <?php  
  $args = array(
           'post_type' => 'portfolio',
           );
  $loop=new WP_Query;
  $count=1;
  if($loop->have_posts()):whiile(have_posts()) :the_post();  
  ?>
  <div class="popup-box <?php echo $count; ?> ">
      <div class="inner-box">        
      </div>
  </div> 
<?php
$count;
endwhile;
endif;
?>
</div>
```

Right Now it is getting all the divs in ajax.php.

Rather it should just display the div which has the class="currentID"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can add ajax request like that.

```
jQuery(".item").click(function(e) {
    var currentID = jQuery(this).attr("id");

    jQuery.ajax({
        method: "POST",
        url: "some.php",
        data: {
            id: currentID,
            location: "Boston"
        }
    })


    .done(function(msg) {
            jQuery(".popup-overlay").html(msg);

            jQuery(".popup-overlay").show();
        });
    });
```

you ajax.php should b like that check it and update me..

```
<?php include("wp-load.php");
$id=$_GET['id'];
 ?> 

  <div class="popup-overlay">
  <?php  
  $args = array( 'post__in' => $sss, 'post_type' => 'portfolio',);
  $loop=new WP_Query;
  $count=1;
  if($loop->have_posts()):whiile(have_posts()) :the_post();  
if($count==$id) {
  ?>
  <div class="popup-box <?php echo $count; ?> ">
      <div class="inner-box">        
      </div>
  </div> 
<?php  }
$count;
endwhile;
endif;
?>
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80465/discussion-on-answer-by-qaisar-satti-how-do-i-show-the-content-through-ajax-in-a).

Answer (score 2):

This is a basic example of how to use AJAX in WordPress. It shows how to take a variable from javascript, pass it to a PHP function (altering it slightly), and then pass it back to the javascript.

This assumes you already know how to enqueue javascript, etc.

Javascript Piece (which you can add in header.php or footer.php or in template file in which it is needed.)

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    // We'll pass this variable to the PHP function example_ajax_request
    var fruit = 'Banana';

    // This does the ajax request
    $.ajax({
        url: ajaxurl,
        data: {
            'action':'example_ajax_request',
            'fruit' : fruit
        },
        success:function(data) {
            // This outputs the result of the ajax request
            console.log(data);
        },
        error: function(errorThrown){
            console.log(errorThrown);
        }
    });  

});
```

PHP Piece (have to include in functions.php)

```
function example_ajax_request() {

    // The $_REQUEST contains all the data sent via ajax
    if ( isset($_REQUEST) ) {

        $fruit = $_REQUEST['fruit'];

        // Let's take the data that was sent and do something with it
        if ( $fruit == 'Banana' ) {
            $fruit = 'Apple';
        }

        // Now we'll return it to the javascript function
        // Anything outputted will be returned in the response
        echo $fruit;

        // If you're debugging, it might be useful to see what was sent in the $_REQUEST
        // print_r($_REQUEST);

    }

    // Always die in functions echoing ajax content
   die();
}

add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_example_ajax_request', 'example_ajax_request' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_example_ajax_request', 'example_ajax_request' );


// If you wanted to also use the function for non-logged in users (in a theme for example)
// add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_example_ajax_request', 'example_ajax_request' );
```

Comment: go through this example you can defiantly get your problem solved.

Comment: Thanks a lot . Saw that post few hrs ago.  Awesome post . got some idea and solved the problemO